# Magento Join Different Tables

Tags: php, mysql, magento, left-join

I have the following code in my Grid.php file:

```
function _prepareCollection () {
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('sfog' => 'sales_flat_order_grid'),
    'main_table.entity_id = sfog.entity_id',
    array('sfog.shipping_name','sfog.billing_name')
);
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('sfo'=>'sales_flat_order'),
    'sfo.entity_id=main_table.entity_id',
    array(
        'sfo.customer_email',
        'sfo.weight',
        'sfo.discount_description',
        'sfo.increment_id',
        'sfo.store_id',
        'sfo.created_at',
        'sfo.status',
        'sfo.base_grand_total',
        'sfo.grand_total'
    )
);
```

I want to add the table sales_order_item as well, but if i add this table i get this error :

Item (Mage_Sales_Model_Order) with the same id "119" already exist

Anyway around this?

Comment: Maybe you could explain in a few words what exactly are you trying to select from the database, so that we can understand what is that select supposed to do.

Comment: Actually i want to display the "SKU,Shipping Cost,Subtotal,Customer Group" on the sales page in Grid.php file.

Comment: put your db structure on http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: @Ahsan you said that you want to add the table sales_order_item as well - could you show the code - how are you trying to add it?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're joining in `soi` meaning `sales_order_item`, group by `soi.item_id` by doing

```
$collection->getSelect()->group('soi.item_id');
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to make the entity_id column of the sales_flat_order_item table be the collection's entity_id column. You will also have to rename the entity_id column of the main_table class in order to avoid an `entity_id` column conflict

```
$collection->getSelect()->joinLeft(
   array('sfoi' => 'sales_flat_order_item'),
   'sfoi.order_id=sfo.entity_id', 
   array(
      'entity_id' => 'sfoi.item_id',  // Re-assign entity_id column
      'main_table_entity_id' => 'main_table.entity_id'  // Rename original entity_id column
   )
)
```

Comment: Just ran into this today: If Magento isn't returning the 'main_table_entity_id' => 'main_table.entity_id' field, set the following:

'main_table_entity_id' => 'CONCAT(main_table.entity_id)'

Answer (score 2):

Apparently joining with sales_order_item is causing more than one row to be returned per order (not surprising), and Magento is attempting to load the row data into a collection that's specifically for orders, which contains a check to ensure that each order only occurs once.  That check is producing the error you see.

To fix this, you can:

- Change the collection class to "sales/order_item_collection" which allows one row for every order item

-OR-

- Not join with sales_order_item, but instead retrieve the set of order items from each order via `getItemsCollection()`

Answer (score 1):

This is because of Auto increment value, which is used as an `id` , which is **unique** to identify the record